# Troubles with .desktop file

Tags: wine, gnome-shell, .desktop

I've successfully installed `Internet Explorer 7` with `winetrick` in a clean prefix.

I can successfully run it from terminal like this:

```
env WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32ie7 wine 'C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore'
```

Then I have created a .desktop entry to appear in gnome-shell menu:

```
.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/IE7/IE7.desktop
```

which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Microsoft Internet Explorer 7
Exec=env WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32ie7 wine 'C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore'
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Comment=Microsoft Internet Explorer 7 Web Browser.
```

I have restarted the shell and now my launcher appears but when I select it nothing happens other than the cursor turning in the rotating wheel for few seconds.
I cannot even get debug message as can't find how to startup the .destkop launcher from terminal.
Can someone help me please?

**EDIT / SOLUTION:**
Ok, sorry I've fond where the issue is:

```
Exec=env WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32ie7 wine 'C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore'
```

should be

```
Exec=env WINEPREFIX=/home/luca/.wine32ie7 wine 'C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore'
```

as `~` seems only having a value in a terminal environment.

Comment: Please post your solution as a separate answer and accept it instead of editing it into the question. Also, you don't need the shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open`), I'm kind of surprised it works with it.

Comment: @terdon - as was I.

Comment: I got the shebang line from a .desktop file automatically generated by wine while installing MS Office

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've fond where the issue is:

```
Exec=env WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32ie7 wine 'C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore'
```

should be

```
Exec=env WINEPREFIX=/home/luca/.wine32ie7 wine 'C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore'
```

as `~` seems only having a value in a terminal environment.